# Make AskedBy_PersonId the foreign column name(instead of the default AskedBy_id) on Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have these tables:

```
create table Person
(
PersonId int identity(1,1) primary key,
PersonName nvarchar(100) not null
);

create table Question
(
QuestionId int identity(1,1) primary key,
QuestionText nvarchar(100) not null,
AskedBy_PersonId int not null references Person(PersonId),
QuestionModifiedBy_PersonId int not null references Person(PersonId)
);
```

And I have these models:

```
public class Question
{
    public virtual int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public virtual Person AskedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Person QuestionModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using automapping with FluentNHibernate, the referencing properties defaults to these database column names:

```
AskedBy_id
QuestionModifiedBy_id
```

How can one make FluentNHibernate make the referencing properties be mapped to this style of foreign  column name?

```
AskedBy_PersonId
QuestionModifiedBy_PersonId
```

As of now, I'm doing it in manual overriding:

```
.Override<Question>(x => 
{
    x.References(y => y.AskedBy).Column("AskedBy_PersonId");
    x.References(y => y.QuestionModifiedBy).Column("QuestionModifiedBy_PersonId");
})
```

I wanted to remove that overriding and want Fluent NHibernate to automatically make the foreign column name follow the naming pattern above

How can I achieved that with Fluent NHibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy with [IReferenceConvention](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Available-conventions) implementation:

```
public class ReferenceConvention : IReferenceConvention
{
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(
            instance.Name + "_" + instance.Property.PropertyType.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

NHibernate should be configured to read the conventions (with something like this):

```
Fluently.Configure()
    //... other configuration
    .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(
        AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Person>()
            .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<ReferenceConvention>());
```